# How to remove host-header meta tag in joomla site?

Tags: php, html, joomla, header, meta-tags

I have LINUX Server and joomla site. I need to remove host-header meta tag.
This tag value is random keywords, not any site-url.
As i'm unable to find what is this tag and after googling i found out that this tag used in IIS server.
I checked whole site from header tags are setting but unable to find out?
Please help me out??

Comment: I do not quite understand that Meta mean. You can try to do handling the .htaccess http://www.askapache.com/htaccess/using-http-headers-with-htaccess.html

Comment: Did you look at the index file of your template? It seems like the problem is more one of mismatch between the meta tag and the meta data.

Answer (score 0):

Check the file of `libraries/joomla/document/html/renderer/head.php`.

You can do some trick within block of *foreach ($document->_metaTags as $type => $tag)*